# Deploying Outlook Web Add-in from Powershell

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to deploy my Outlook Web-Add in through Powershell or EWS commandline. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, please refer [deploying outlook web-addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-app?view=exchange-ps)